# -[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios7, uipopover

I have a class (ViewOpenAppointments) where I create and display a UIPopover.  This is the code to define the popover in my .h file:

```
@interface ViewOpenAppointments : UIView  {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popoverController;
-(void)createOpenAppointmentsPopover: (UIButton *) obViewOpenAppts;
@end
```

I have a check in the code that if the popover is visible, dismiss it.  This is the code:

```
    //  create popover
UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
//    UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 650, 416)];
ViewOpenAppointments *popoverView = [[ViewOpenAppointments alloc]     initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 650, 416)];

popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(650.0, 416.0);

//  create the popover controller
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]  initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
popoverController.delegate = (id)self;
[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(650, 416) animated:NO];

if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(650, 416, 10, 50) inView: obViewOpenAppts
                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

The problem is that the code to dismiss the popover is never hit, which means it's not visible.  But I still get the error message (described in the question title).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you don't retain the controller, it is deallocated even while visible and you dont

Comment: The controller IS being retained... look at the code from the .h file

Comment: it isn't ;) thats what the 'issue' shows. you would need to show us who holds onto the instance of ViewOpenAppointments that shows the popover

Comment: How do I do that?  (all of my code is above, so please tell me what I have to change)  :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a complete popover management example:

```
@interface ViewController () <UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController* currentPop;
@end

@implementation ViewController     

-(IBAction)doPopover1:(id)sender {
    Popover1View1* vc = [[Popover1View1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Popover1View1" bundle:nil];

    UIPopoverController* pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];
    self.currentPop = pop;
    [pop presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender
                permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                animated:YES];
    pop.passthroughViews = nil;
    // make ourselves delegate so we learn when popover is dismissed
    pop.delegate = self;
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)pc {
    self.currentPop = nil;
}
```

By checking `self.currentPop` you can make sure you don't present two popovers at once (illegal anyway).

Comment: Note that if you did try to present two popovers at once with this code, you would get exactly the message you are getting, because you would be setting `currentPop` again, thus releasing the previous `currentPop` which is still controlling the first popover which is still up.

Comment: Thanks Matt... I'll work with it and get back to both of you... SD